Weird laptop keyboard failure mode
I've already gotten a replacement, so it's more of a curiosity long shot to see if anyone has seen anything like this before or happen to know the reason.
So my asus rog g14 keyboard has 4 most-of-the-time-unresponsive keys J K L ;.
There are 2 ways to activate them when they stop working.

Apply pressure from the backside bottom of the laptop, then press really hard. Sometimes doing this would fix them for a while.

Alternatively, they can be activated without extra force applied if i press them while another button is pressed. E.g. if I hold I then press K it just comes out effortlessly, or say if I wanna type lowercase K I can press Caps Lock, hold Shift, then press K.


It's so consistently weird... Like, if the problem is mechanical 2 probably wont work and vice versa if it's electrical?

My old Acer laptop had a similar issue with the up and right arrow keys. they would work sometimes, and these keys also worked well when used simultaneously with another key. However, they functioned in BIOS.
About a month ago, I removed the keyboard ribbon cable to replace the fan, and I noticed that my arrow keys were also fixed, so I think it's because the ribbon cable was loose.

Ah interesting, I'll give it a try. Thanks for the edit suggestion, but I literally mean failure mode as a thing.

Sounds like an intermittent connection, and with those four keys being right next to each other would seem to indicate something leaked below the keys or some kind of hardware damage to the PCB/ribbon cable for those keys - could be the ribbon cable connection on the motherboard, the contact point under those keys needing to be cleaned, the keyboard PCB itself, possibly the ribbon cable itself coming off the keyboard PCB, or the keyboard PCB randomly failed. Were the UEFI hardware diagnostics run on the keyboard (usually accessible from the UEFI boot menu)? After reseating the ribbon cable?

Connectors that sits in place for a long time can build up oxidization, moving the connector back and forth, disconnecting and reconnecting, using a pencil eraser on portions or similar may make any problem go away, at least for some time.
Oxide simply creates elevated electrical resistance between the connector parts, which may cause trouble if it gets "too high".
But then, the description (pressing other keys) also indicates that there might be actually broken (cracked) wiring or soldering in the keyboard.

Thanks for the answers. I was hoping to validate during replacement but turns out taking out the keyboard part involves +50 tiny screws, and I couldn't find a way to have the flex cables connected while it's disassembled  (I only remember to do this after taking out the keyboard). Couldn't do it for science.
